# How do I rebuild micropython firmware adding my own C++ code

Tags: c++, esp32, micropython

I want to run my C++ code no micropython

For that I referred  https://github.com/stinos/micropython-wrap this wrapper.

Uploaded required wrapper files on the board and tried to run

```
#include <micropython-wrap-master/functionwrapper.h>

//function we want to call from within a MicroPython script
std::vector< std::string > FunctionToBeCalled ( std::vector< std::string > vec )
{
  for( auto& v : vec )
    v += "TRANSFORM";
  return vec;
}

//function names are declared in structs
struct CppFunction
{
  func_name_def( TransformList )
};

extern "C"
{
  void RegisterMyModule(void)
  {
    //register a module named 'foo'
    auto mod = upywrap::CreateModule( "foo" );

    //register our function with the name 'TransformList'
    //conversion of a MicroPython list of strings is done automatically
    upywrap::FunctionWrapper wrapfunc( mod );
    wrapfunc.Def< CppFunction::TransformList >( FunctionToBeCalled );
  }
}
```

Run it using

```
import foo

print(foo.TransformList(['a', 'b']))  # Prints ['aTRANSFORM', 'bTRANSFORM']
```

But later I found this will not help. Because I need to integrate my C++ code into micropython code and rebuild the firmware to get it run.

I am not able to figure out

1. How to integrate my C++ in existing micropython code
2. How to recompile the firmware ( Because when I try to use `make` command, it does not seem working )

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: How does it help here? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: OP did not asks about LUA , and none of the LUA related answers answer the question of calling C++ from the higher langue. ( in both cases would need cross-compilation on a PC and then the flashing of the new firmware.

Answer (score 2):

MicroPython offers two options of adding  C/C++ code to it.
Note that both require cross-compilation of that code on a PC.
AFAIK there is no option to compile on a microcontroller (due to obvious constraints)

**1) MicroPython Native Module**
One of the main advantages of using native .mpy files is that native machine code can be imported by a script dynamically, without the need to rebuild the main MicroPython firmware.
Essentially you compile C to MicroPython bytecode and store that in a module.
Then you import that module into Python
http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/natmod.html#minimal-example

**2) MicroPython C Module**
You add you C/C++ code as a custom module, and then compile and link that together into a new firmware image.
http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html#micropython-external-c-modules

The approach you refer to, is based on the 2nd method, and requires cross-compilation.

C or C++ support will depend on the compiler/languages supported for you port/hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need necessarily need to recompile, you can build a C++ user module. Which has been done for ESP32 already, see discussion at https://github.com/stinos/micropython-wrap/issues/5#issuecomment-704328111.

Specifically if you run `make USER_C_MODULES=../../../micropython-wrap CFLAGS_EXTRA="-DMODULE_UPYWRAPTEST_ENABLED=1"` from the ESP32 port directory, this should build a user C++ module containing micropython-wrap's unittests, so that should be a good starting point: copy the relevant files (cmodule.c, module.cpp and micropython.mk from the tests directory) and modify the code.